# DevExpress.XtraEditors.CheckedComboBoxEdit Items are displaying as bold after migration

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have migrated my application to `DevExpress` 15.2.I am getting my `DevExpress.XtraEditors.CheckedComboBoxEdit` items are displaying in bold.I have set following properties.Please let me know if I missed any property.I tried with Font property but `selected Item` is only changing not all the Items.

```
this.cmbTemplates.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(503, 618);
this.cmbTemplates.Name = "cmbTemplates";
this.cmbTemplates.Properties.Buttons.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton[] { new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Combo)});
this.cmbTemplates.Properties.SelectAllItemCaption = "Select All";
this.cmbTemplates.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 20);
this.cmbTemplates.TabIndex = 93;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
cmbTemplates.Properties.AppearanceDropDown.Font = new 
Font(cmbTemplates.Properties.AppearanceDropDown.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Comment: `this.cmbTemplates.Properties.AppearanceDropDown.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular); `worked for me.Thank you OUMGHAR :)   You saved my time :)  Thank you so much